# NextJS component not rerendering upon update

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have been reading different things about useEffect, useState and rerendering, but I cannot understand the issue here.
The data update itself works fine but for some reason, I need to refresh the page to get the updated content.

I have noticed a common issue with arrays in my research is when React doesn't understand data has changed and keeps the same reference, hence the `setGames([...updatedGames])` but to no avail.

```
const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    const gamesRepo: Game[] = repo.getAll()
    return { props: { gamesRepo } }
}

const Home: NextPage = ({ gamesRepo }: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
    const [games, setGames] = useState(gamesRepo)

    useEffect(() => {
        let gamesIdToUpdate: number[] = []
        // ... filtering the ids to update here ...

        if (gamesIdToUpdate.length > 0) {
            const endpoint = '/api/games/update'
            const options = { method: 'POST', //... }
            fetch(endpoint, options)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then((updatedGames: Game[]) => {
                    setGames([...updatedGames])
                })
        }
    }, [games])
    
    return (
        <>
            <div className={styles.container}>
                games.map((game: Game) => (
                        <GameCard key={game.id} gameData={game} />
                    ))
                <AddGameCard></AddGameCard>
            </div>
        </>
    );
```

Comment: It looks like you may have an infinite loop. Every time `game` changes, you update `game`. Unless you've removed code that prevents this. I do not see any state mutations, so the `[...updatedGames]` doesn't look to be necessary.

Comment: Could you provide more debugging details? Such as `console.log(updatedGames)` right before you call `setGames`?

Comment: Yes I use getStaticProps to get the initial data. But I fetch updated data on the client side through the `useEffect` hook. Sorry If I mislead you with my getStaticProps excerpt

Comment: best would be to have codepen where we can look at, so all the confusion could be avoided

Comment: I did console.log updateGames received from fetching the data, and it works just fine !
I also tried to console.log(games) after the `setGames([...updatedGames] call but I believe the output is not to be trusted since setGames is asynchronous.

Comment: Im still quite sure the problem is that you server side render this and then try to use useEffect to upate data  after its already rendered, I would need to see a codesandbox to be exactly sure whats up though

Comment: But then how I should I proceed if I cannot use `useEffect` after rendering? To give a little more context, the idea here is to fetch the data stored on initial rendering then update asynchronously in the background if some data is more than x days old and rerender the page once it's done.

Comment: @DamianBusz this isn't a problem. Re-rendering with new data is a key feature of React.

Comment: @fassn If your console log before the state update is showing you the data you expect, then I don't believe your question is answerable as-is. The JSX in your question is invalid. In order to answer the question we will need a [mre].

Comment: @BrianThompson but if you server side render a page, it will not apply data to this. You would need to specificaly use a client side rendered component that would rerender on data update, this can be done in next.js with next/dynamic

Comment: Server side data sets the **initial** state. The client running code is free to update that data in state. A dynamic import is not needed.

Comment: I might be overconfused in here, we need minimal sandbox to look further though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks to @Damian Busz and @Brian Thomson for helping out here.
I figured the solution to my problem and understood quite a bit in the way.

There were different problems, some were indeed not shown in the excerpts I shared. To make this thread useful for future readings:

```
 export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = () => {
    // getting the data from a JSON file
    const gamesRepo: Game[] = repo.getAll()
    return { props: { gamesRepo } }
}

const Home: NextPage = ({ gamesRepo }: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
    const [games, setGames] = useState(gamesRepo)

    useEffect(() => {
        // checking if the data is 3 days old or more
        const today = new Date().getDate()
        let gamesIdToUpdate: number[] = []
        for (const game of games) {
            const lastUpdated = new Date(game.dateUpdated).getDate()
            const dateDiff = today - lastUpdated
            if (dateDiff >= 3) {
                gamesIdToUpdate.push(game.id)
            }
        }
        // actually updating the data that is 3 days old or more
        if (gamesIdToUpdate.length > 0) {
            const endpoint = '/api/games/update'
            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(gamesIdToUpdate),
            }
            fetch(endpoint, options)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then((updatedGames: Game[]) => {
                    setGames([...updatedGames])
                })
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <div className={styles.container}>
                {
                    games.length > 0 &&
                     games.map((game: Game) => (
                        <GameCard key={game.id} gameData={game} />
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </>
    );
```

1. Some noticed the `useEffect(..., [games])` in my original post that was indeed causing multiple calls to useEffect even though I just needed it once.
2. The problem wasn't in this component, the `setGames` state was working fine all along! It was in the GameCard child component. Here it is:

```
export const GameCard = (props: { gameData: Game }) => {
    const [game, setGame] = useState({...props.gameData})

    // I didn't have useEffect before in this component, hence it was never triggering a re-render !
    useEffect(() => {
        setGame(props.gameData)
    }, [props.gameData])

// some other methods here
...

return (
        <div className="flex justify-center">
            <div className="w-64 my-10 outline outline-2 shadow-md shadow-deep-blue">
                { game.name }
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

Since I am using the state variable `game` in my component's template and for the other methods in this component instead of the props directly, I mixed up both concepts (props and state variables) and was expecting the component to re-render automatically upon change, which it clearly couldn't since inner state changes are not tracked automatically by React.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but for someone looking at the accepted answer above, using a useEffect like this in React is an anti-pattern.

The `GameCard` component can be refactored as follows:

```js
export const GameCard = ({ gameData }: { gameData: Game }) => {

// some other methods here

return (
        <div className="flex justify-center">
            <div className="w-64 my-10 outline outline-2 shadow-md shadow-deep-blue">
                { gameData.name }
            </div>
        </div>
)
}
```

The approach with a `useEffect` is sometimes referred to as deriving state from props and results in unnecessary re-renders that often cause bugs.